# Find next higher value in DataView row

Tags: c#, select, filter, find, dataview

I have a **DataView** which in the row `PathName` contains names like:

```
"C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1993492240-2256127134-121505747-1000"
"C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1993492240-2256127134-121505747-1004"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\dao360.dll"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\1.0\Microsoft.Ink.dll"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\de-DE\InkObj.dll.mui"
"C:\Windows\System32\de-DE\Query.dll.mui"
"C:\Windows\System32\de-DE\query.exe.mui"
"C:\Windows\System32\de-DE\quser.exe.mui"
"C:\Windows\System32\de-DE\Qutil.dll.mui"
"C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\bth.inf_amd64_neutral_de0494b6391d872c\bthport.sys"
"C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\bth.inf_amd64_neutral_de0494b6391d872c\BTHUSB.SYS"
"C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\bth.inf_amd64_neutral_e54666f6a3e5af91\bthenum.sys"
```

**For *any* given path I need to get the subfolders.**

Sub folders for the path **"C:\"**

```
"$Recycle.Bin"
"Program Files (x86)"
"Windows"
```

What I am currently doing is:

- Extend the present rowfilter: `MyDataView.rowfilter += " and (PathName LIKE 'c:\%')"`
- First I find `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1993492240-2256127134-121505747-1000` and extract `C:\$Recycle.Bin`
- Then I iterate through the rows till I find something different from `C:\$Recycle.Bin`, like `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`

The `DataView` may contain 100.000 and more entries so this way takes very long.

One possibility would be to extend the rowfilter after every hit:

```
MyDataView.rowfilter += " and (PathName LIKE 'c:\%')" + " and (PathName NOT LIKE 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\%')".
```

But the path names may get very long and this will lead to a stack overflow in the rowfilter.

Is there any other way, like "get the next higher value"?

**Edit**
The subfolders must be found for **any** given path not only for `c:\`

Comment: You are searching just the first subfolder of C or do you need every single subfolder?

Comment: @steve for any path. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this could be done with a single line of Linq
(Splitted in more than one line for readability)

```
var dirs = dv.Table
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x.Field<string>("PathName")))
             .Distinct();
```

The trick consist in using the `Path.GetDirectoryName` to extract from each row the value of the field `PathName` and, using the `Select` method, create an enumerable of strings. Then the `Distinct` method returns just the unique directory names from the collection.

If your DataView has been filtered for some other condition and you want to keep this condition to exclude a subset of records then you could use the `Where` method to extract the required records. For example, to exclude every record that starts with "C:\WINDOWS" you could write

```
var dirs = dv.Table
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Where(k => !k.Field<string>("PathName").StartsWith(@"C:\WINDOWS"))
             .Select(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x.Field<string>("PathName")))
             .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds very promissing. But for that I need to convert it to a DataTable. Doesn't `MyDataView.ToTable()` create a copy of the whole DataView?

Comment: DataView has a reference to the original table, No need to create a new copy of an existing table. How do you create the MyDataView variable?

Comment: But `MyDataView.Table`doesn't contain the rowfilter. This is why I use a DataView.

Comment: I can't see what is the previous filter applied to the original table to get a subset of records in the DataView, but I presume that you could apply a Where to the full table to isolate the records needed. Could you explain the logic that filters your table?

Comment: The DataTable, which the DataView is based on, contains several fields, like attributes and states of the path (application logic, not the file attributes from ntfs). The user can set different filters which kind of paths he wants to see (attribute: IsFile and HasNoDenyAce and ....). These are provided with the rowfilter. Anyway, cool answer. I will have to implement the rowfilter in the LINQ expression and forget the DataView. Thanks!